# Apache Ant - Installing Maven Ant Tasks

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, ant, installation

This is for running files as Ant builds in Eclipse. I have my Ant set up, now I need to install the Maven Ant Tasks. I followed the instructions on the Maven website: downloaded the JAR and put it in my .ant/lib, and double checked that my environment variables were correct. When I try to run as an Ant build in Eclipse, however, it gives me this error:

```
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
    -C:\Users\arempel\Documents\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib
    -C:\Users\arempel\.ant\lib
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

Now I know there are a ton of resolved questions like this that have been answered, but I've tried all of the solutions I could find to no avail. I've tried using -lib in prompt, tried setting the `classpath` variable, tried playing around with my environment variables, but I'm still screwing up somehow.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running Ant within Eclipse, it is Eclipse itself which is managing the classpath of Ant.

Look into the global preferences of Eclipse, and then into the Ant/Runtime panel. The first tab, 'Classpath' is the one you want to modify. Click on the 'Global Entries' and then hit the button 'Add JARs...'. Select the jar of the Maven Ant Tasks and you're done.

Comment: Hi, I just tried this and ran the build from Eclipse, but it's not working for me. I also tried passing in the -lib lib argument from command line.